# How to implement switch case in python using Dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am tring to implement the switch case using dict but the function unable to call.so like the below code if the select 1 how addEmployee() method will be call.

```
  employee_dictionary = {}       
  while proceed:

       print('\n Employee Management System\n')
       print('\t1. Add a new employee')
       print('\t2. Delete an existing employee')
       print('\t3. Save and Quit\n')
       option_choice = int(input('Enter an option to continue: '))

       # Map each choice to the functions below using a dictionary
       options = {
           1:emp.addEmployeeInDict(),
           2:emp.deleteEmpUsingID(emp),
           3:"Exit"
       }
       proceed = options[option_choice](employee_dictionary)
```

Add Employee Code :

```
def addEmployeeInDict(self):
employeeDetails = {}
      old_detailsOfEmp=[]
      new_detailsOfEmp = []
   try:
           for i in range(1):
               emp_ID = int(input("Enter emp ID: "))
               old_detailsOfEmp.clear()
               for j in range(3):
                   if j==0:
                     emp_Name = input(f"Enter Emp Name :")
                     old_detailsOfEmp.append(emp_Name)
                   elif j==1:
                     emp_dept = input(f"Enter Emp Dept :")
                     old_detailsOfEmp.append(emp_dept)
                   else:
                     emp_Sal = int(input(f"Enter Emp Sal :"))
                     old_detailsOfEmp.append(emp_Sal)
               new_detailsOfEmp=copy.deepcopy(old_detailsOfEmp)
               employeeDetails[emp_ID] = new_detailsOfEmp
               proceed = True
           return proceed
```

Comment: Add Employee Code : Code works fine with out using switch

Comment: Where have you defined these functions? Your dictionary contains strings, not functions?

Comment: I have also tried with he below changes. options = {
               1:emp.addEmployeeInDict(),
               2:emp.deleteEmpUsingID(emp),
               3:"Exit"
           } Now the question is after adding the employee it should  ask for main menu but goes for delete a employee

Comment: Don't call the function in the dict (using `()` will call the function when you define the dictionary). Just add a reference to it: `{1:emp.addEmployeeInDict, 2: emp.deleteEmpUsingID}` so you can call it later.

Comment: i tried this {1:emp.addEmployeeInDict, 2: emp.deleteEmpUsingID} now the error is coming TypeError: addEmployeeInDict() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given becausei passed self in add employee

Comment: The error is telling you `addEmployeeInDict` does not take any additional arguments other than self. `self` is passed in automatically. But you are passing it a dictionary as well. What should it do with  `employee_dictionary` that you are passing in?

Comment: here :     proceed = options[option_choice](employee_dictionary)
TypeError: addEmployeeInDict() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. .......proceed = options[option_choice](employee_dictionary)

Comment: got it i have to pass Dict as well. working fine now....

Comment: one question why we should not call dict  in this way using ().............................................................options = {
           1:emp.addEmployeeInDict(),
           2:emp.deleteEmpUsingID(emp),
           3:"Exit"
       }

Comment: As stated above, doing `1:emp.addEmployeeInDict()` will call the function when you define the dict. This means you will create a dict where the values in the dict are the *returned results* of the function. That's not what you want.